# Not able to Call action in Struts2.5.16

Tags: struts2

[Project Structure in Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zc14L.jpg)

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>Struts2Starter</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.5//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.5.dtd">
<struts>
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="getTutorial" class="org.awanish.action.TutorialAction">
                <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
                <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

**ActionClass**

```
package org.awanish.action;

public class TutorialAction {
    public String execute() {
        System.out.println("Hello from execute");
        return "success";
            }

}
```

When running the above project in tomcat-8.0.43 container, getting my welecome page but when tried to test the action in browser http://localhost:8080/Struts2Starter/getTutorial.action it gives this

[Error in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/800mG.jpg)

Comment: Could be anything at this point. Anything in the console logs on startup? Are you deploying to the context you think you are?

Answer (score 1):

```
1.check in logs if:Hello from execute is printed
2. check if the jsp exists in the correct path
3. .action is not required at the end
4.<action name="getTutorial" class="org.awanish.action.TutorialAction" method="define your own method and try calling it">
5.Add jars at runtime also inside WEB-INF/lib folder

 http://localhost:8080/Struts2Starter/getTutorial

And if you begineer try using struts 2.3 rather than struts 2.5 ,you will get lots of example:https://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-hello-world-example/

Download code and build on top of it if still facing issue
```